# tuleap : Script error while adding a template following instruction in tracker plugin

Tags: tuleap

I am trying to add some tracker templates to be able to user Tracker. The Site default template doesn't have Tracker.

I am using Tuleap version 8.5.99.66-1.el6

The tracker plug-in recommends the below :

$ cd /usr/share/codendi/
    $ vi plugins/tracker/bin/import_tracker_xml_template.php (if you need to change the admin login and password, modify lines 19 and 20)
    $ src/utils/php-launcher.sh plugins/tracker/bin/import_tracker_xml_template.php plugins/tracker/www/resources/templates/choose_a_template.xml

I did this, but found an error of what I think is an include missing. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong. Is there a simplier way to install or create a template ?

src/utils/php-launcher.sh plugins/tracker/bin/import_tracker_xml_template.php plugins/tracker/www/resources/templates/Tracker_UserStories.xml
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TrackerXmlImport' not found in /usr/share/tuleap/plugins/tracker/bin/import_tracker_xml_template.php on line 26

Fatal error: Class 'TrackerXmlImport' not found in /usr/share/tuleap/plugins/tracker/bin/import_tracker_xml_template.php on line 26

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: You can edit your question so the information is included in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://gerrit.tuleap.net/#/c/4469/) on this version of Tuleap, please [upgrade](http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/update.html) to a newer version

Comment: Thanks Manuel, that worked. Also I was wondering why by default the project template doesn't have trackers enabled. I think its an important feature for anyone. Cheers !